# Finding area of a part of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I have the values of $L$, $R$ and $W$ in the picture below. 
The circle is drawn though the center of the rectangle. And the circle will always intersect the rectangle.

How can I find the area of the part in grey for any such rectangle and circle of this type?

[image]

Comment: I presume the circle's center coincides with the rectangle's, i.e.: with the point of intersection of the rectangle's diagonals, right?

Comment: @DonAntonio the circle is drawn though the center of the rectangle. and the circle will always intersect the rectangle.

Comment: Try here for some [help](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp16/circlesectors.htm)

Comment: @Swatak: I suppose it's clear what you mean, but "the circle is drawn through the center of the rectangle" is false here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints.

The area of a sector (a piece of the pie) with central angle $\theta$ is $\pi R^2 \theta/(2\pi)$.

From your diagram, let's say that $\theta$ is the angle between $B$ and $C$.  Call the center of the circle $O$.  Then the area of triangle $BOC$ is

$$A(BOC) = R\sin (\theta/2) \cdot R \cos (\theta/2).$$

Taking the difference of these two will get you the area of the white cap.

To calculate the center angle, drop a perpendicular from the center of the circle to the right side of the rectangle.  Call the point of intersection $E$.  Then triangle $EOA$ is a right triangle with one of the angles $\theta/2$.  The adjacent side has length $w/2$, and the hypotenuse is $R$.  This makes
$$\sin (\theta/2) = \frac{w/2}{R}.$$

You can use the Pythagorean theorem to find the other side, and then find $\cos(\theta/2)$.

To find $\theta$ directly, then, just use an inverse trig function:

$$\sin^{-1} (\sin (\theta/2)) = ...$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: i don't know how to calculate the center angle :(. can you help please

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $ A,B,C,D $ are sketched as distinct points,evaluate

$$ 4 \int_0^{ w/2} \sqrt{ R^2- x^2} dx $$

as a  standard integral.